# angular not loading quickly enough to prevent ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty vanilla ng-repeat statement in my template that is meant to repeat a set of images in table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
     <td><img src={{d.image}}></img></td>
</tr>
```

All the images load properly (they all exist and they all show up in the table) but I see the following error in the console when I'm testing locally (and also when I deploy):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found) http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Bd.image%7D%7D
```

I think what's happening here is that the error is being thrown before Angular has loaded — which makes sense, since without Angular, looking for {{d.image}} should throw an error — and then once Angular loads, the images load correctly.

How do I get the browser to not try and render {{d.image}} until Angular is loaded? I put `ng-cloak` into the `<body>` tag but that doesn't seem to be helping. Am I even thinking about this the correct way?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like any images are being loaded in the sample code you provided. Is that really what your actual code is like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem tends to happen when you're using the `src` attribute to interpolate the path of your images. Use **[`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)** instead of using the `src` attribute.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
     <td><img ng-src="{{d.image}}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Am not asking this question !